# Deployment / Validation apex test results

Tags: apex, unit-test, deployment, apextestrunresult

Does anyone know where the test results (especially runtime) are stored for tests that are run during a validation/deployment ?
I know the objects where the test results are but how do they relate to the deployment / validation runs ?

-Jani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the test results are stored but the AsyncApexJobId is null in ApexTestResult for those that are executed as part of a validation / deployment. It is not null if it is executed as part of apex test execution.